# Hangfire Server: deploying business code changes to the server- best practise

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, hangfire

i am new to hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io/). I have a server running and the examples are running too.
Now i want to go an step further and try to execute a complex business job. As i understand i need to deploy the business code ,lets call it BC.dll and the dependencies to the server.
I need to do this by adding the dependencies to the server code(in my case a [asp net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) proj.).

So every time i changes anything in the business code(BC.dll) i need to  ?!

1. stop the server
2. open server code
3. update the dependencies
4. build the server
5. deploy the server

Are there any common good deploy strategies ?!

Or do are there any other way to do this ?

Install in the GAC every time ?

thanks in advance
christian